# Renderer.readRenderTargetPixels?

Tags: three.js

The GPU picking example uses method: readRenderTargetPixels

but this doesn't seem to exist.  Has it been removed? Is there an equivalent?

Example: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes_gpu

Comment: Looks like this function doesn't appear in the documentation, but is still present in the lib sources... Are you sure this doesn't still exist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Aracthor commented, [`WebGLRenderer.readRenderTargetPixels()`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/eee231960882f6f3b6113405f524956145148146/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L5939) exists, but is undocumented.

(three.js r71)

Comment: Thanks both.  Seems it was just missing from the npm build (r70)